# JavaScript/RegExp replace portion of string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string something like:

```
foo title:2012-01-01 bar
```

Where I need to get the 'title:2012-01-01' and replace the date part '2012-01-01' to a special format. I just am not good at RegExp and currently have:

```
'foo from:2012-01-01 bar'.replace(/from:([a-z0-9-]+)/i, function() {
    console.log(arguments);
    return 'replaced';
})
```

and that returns

```
foo replaced bar
```

which is a start but not exactly correct. I need the 'from:' not to be replaced, just the '2012-01-01' be replaced. Tried using (?:from:) but that didn't stop it from replacing 'from:'. Also, I need to take into account that there may be a space between 'from:' and '2012-01-01' so it needs to match this also:

```
foo title: 2012-01-01 bar
```

Comment: Somewhat confused: is 'title' a keyword? What about 'from'? Or are you looking for any word followed by a colon? Giving us at least one example of both expected inputs and outputs would be tremendously helpful here.

Comment: Also, is logging the arguments a requirement or is this just debug code?

Comment: 'title' was a typo on my part, should have been 'from'. The console.log(arguments) is just debug code, will be doing some date calc later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you need it to; tested it myself:

```
'foo from:2012-01-01 bar'.replace(/(\w+:\s?)([a-z0-9-]+)/i, function(match, $1) {
    console.log(arguments);
    return $1 + 'replaced';
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/zD68Q/)

It will match both `title: etc` and `from:etc`.  The `$1` is the first matched group, the `(\w+:\s?)`, the `\w` matches any word character, while the `\s?` matches for at least one or no spaces.

Comment: If you're looking for at least one space (possibly more) I would suggest replacing the `\s?` with `\s*` (zero or more space characters).

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always `from:...` there should be no need to capture the 'from' text at all:

```
'foo from:2012-01-01 bar'.replace(/from:\s*([a-z0-9-]+)/i, function() {
    console.log(arguments);
    return 'from: replaced';
});
```

If you want to retain the spacing however, you could do the following:

```
'foo from:2012-01-01 bar'.replace(/from:(\s*)([a-z0-9-]+)/i, function(match, $1) {
    console.log(arguments);
    return 'from:' + $1 + 'replaced';
});
```